# Running a python script at various intervals during the day?

Tags: python, cron

I need to run a python script at various times depending on the day. The requires are:

**On Weekdays:**

- Start 7 am - End 12 pm => run script every 5 minutes
- Start 12:00 pm - End 4 pm => run script every 30 minutes
- Start 4 pm - End 9 pm => run script every 5 minutes
- Start 9 pm - End 7 am => run script every hour

**On Weekends:**

- Run script every half hour

I've done some simple cron stuff before, but it doesn't seem like cron can handle this kind of granularity.

I've thought about creating a bash script where it would check the time and run the python script if conditions are met, but I run into problems of how to persist time through each run of the bash script.

Comment: cron can  handle this kind of granularity perfectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just register multiple entries in your crontab:

```
#
# Weekdays
#

# Start 7 am - End 12 pm => run script every 5 minutes
*/5  7-11      * * mon-fri *   yourscript

# Start 12:00 pm - End 4 pm => run script every 30 minutes
0,30 12-15     * * mon-fri *   yourscript

# Start 4 pm - End 9 pm => run script every 5 minutes
*/5  16-20     * * mon-fri *   yourscript

# Start 9 pm - End 7 am => run script every hour
0    0-6,21-23 * * mon-fri *   yourscript

# 
# Weekends
#

# Run script every half hour
0,30 *         * * sat-sun *   yourscript
```

Cron can handle such granularity *just fine*.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working in Windows, there is a program called task scheduler that allows you to do exactly this.

If you are working in Linux(which it sounds like you are), I believe crontab will do what you want.  [Here is a tutorial](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/) that I found, I hope that it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at apscheduler: http://pythonhosted.org/APScheduler/
and dateutil.rrule: http://labix.org/python-dateutil

With those two you can make a lot of chron like rules from within python, which makes it more easy to transfer between machines and OSes.. :)